# Como puedo realizar un detector de colores en Python utilizando Opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

Como dice el título, estoy intentando crear un detector de colores de objetos - una cámara debe ser capaz de hacerlo -. Estaba pensando ocupar el detector de colores RGB que tiene Opencv, pero no sabría como tener una "base de datos" con las distintas tonalidades de los colores. Por ejemplo, que detecte el color azul marino, pero que lo clasifique netamente como azul. Tampoco sabría como hacer que detecte el objeto en comparación al ambiente, y secciones de este objeto, por ejemplo una polera puesta en una persona, o una persona en sí.

Comment: Puedes agregar lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Hay una librería llamada HSV, que permite detectar los colores dependiendo del umbral o espectro entregado al programa.